# How to get expandable list items back in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

If I remember correctly, Nautilus would let me expand folders when they where in a listview. It used to have little triangles which you could click to expand the contents of that folder:

[image]

Kind of like how it is on Mac OSX as well:

[image]

But with the current version of Nautilus in 14.04, I don't see that option anymore. Does anybody know how I can get it back? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Edit`, `Preferences`, `Display` tab and check the box at `List View` which says `Navigate folders in a tree`

[image]